# Is there a way to validate/parse a YAML file with go-template variables in it?

Tags: go, yaml, kubernetes-helm, unmarshalling, go-templates

I have a "YAML" file.  And I want to validate it before I render the go-template variables in it. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default "tea" | quote }}
  food: {{ .Values.favorite.food | upper | quote }}
```

The typical YAML parser doesn't work here, as it will parse `{` as the start of a map.

```
err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, &Content)
// Failed to parse the provided YAML: yaml: line 4: did not find expected key
```

I wonder if there is any package that can help me do this?  I've searched online for a while but have no luck.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can render it and _then_ check if it's a valid yaml. But before that, you don't know if some value of the input variables will make the yaml invalid.

Comment: Execute it as a template first, then parse it as YAML - though one might wonder why you'd want to do this in the first place. Also avoid asking things like "I wonder if there is any package that can help me do this?" - there's a valid question here, but that question specifically (asking for library recommendations) is specifically off-topic on SO.

Comment: You can render it with `"missingkey=zero"` and without data so that the expressions simply get removed, then try to load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just the YAML parser complaining: that actually is invalid YAML (because the `{...}` is inline mapping syntax).  That looks like it comes from the Kubernetes [Helm](https://helm.sh) deployment tool, and some routine-but-interesting uses really actually require rendering the YAML.

In practice what you probably want is to use the [`helm template`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) command to render a chart to multi-document YAML, and then run a YAML validator on that.  It doesn't seem to be documented, but Helm version 3 will actually do this validation on its own (Helm 2 doesn't) so if your chart produces invalid YAML you'll get an error at that point.

The way Helm works, it interprets this "YAML" file as a plain text file and applies Go `text/template` templating to it, and then reads it back as YAML.  To some extent you could make this valid YAML by quoting strings yourself:

```yaml
name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-configmap"
```

But there's some fairly common constructs where this will actually break the generated YAML.  For example, the `helm create` template [generates](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/chartutil/create.go)

```yaml
{{/* _helpers.tpl */}}
{{- define "<CHARTNAME>.labels" -}}
helm.sh/chart: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.chart" . }}
{{- end -}}
```

```yaml
metadata:
  name: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "<CHARTNAME>.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

and no amount of quoting will make this valid YAML.  It's very possible to put something into the "labels" helper template that's not valid in a YAML mapping context and you want to catch that in your validation stage.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Evaluate the template first.